# how to launch an external app from an app using webintents on android

Tags: javascript, cordova

hello am developing an app using phonegap, that is supposed to be able to launch an external app from it.

e.g "watsapp" or "facebook"

i am using a plugin called [net.tunts.webintent](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/363)

this is what i have tried to do to launch an external app

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function app() {
                alert('open');
                window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
                    action: 'com.whatsapp'}, 
                    function() {alert('Started!?');}, 
                    function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
                );
            }
        </script>
```

but i kip getting this error "Failed to open URL via Android Intent"

can anyone give an advise or solution on solving this